# How to replace backward slash (\) to forward slash (/) using jmeter BeanShell

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I have declared a user defined variable as 'projectHome' using below BeanShell which returns the absolute path of the jmx file.

`${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}`

**On Windows it returns**: projectHome=C:\Users\dd\Desktop\API_Testing

**On MacOS it returns**: 
projectHome=/Users/dd/Desktop/API_Testing

The variable value is working fine in following BeanShell Sampler on **MacOS**:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;
//Default separator
char SEPARATOR = ',';
//function write line in csv
public void writeLine(FileWriter writer, String[] params, char separator) {
    boolean firstParam = true;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String param = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        //get param
        param = params[i];
        log.info(param);
        //if the first param in the line, separator is not needed
        if (!firstParam) {
            stringBuilder.append(separator);
        }
        //Add param to line
        stringBuilder.append(param);
        firstParam = false;
    }
    //prepare file to next line
    stringBuilder.append("\n");
    //add to file the line
    log.info(stringBuilder.toString());
    writer.append(stringBuilder.toString());
}
//get path of csv file (creates new one if its not exists)
String csvFile = "${projectHome}/tenant_details.csv"; 
String[] params = {"${Email}"};
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile, true);
writeLine(fileWriter, params, SEPARATOR);
//proper close to file
fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```

When I am running the script on Windows machine, it is failing because of the path having backslash.

**How can I convert the backslash to forward slash within the same BeanShell Sampler so that it can work on Windows as well as MacOS?**

Comment: on windows it's normal to have backslash as file separator. how exactly it fails? ps: `"a\\b\\c".replace('\\','/');` will return `"a/b/c"`

Comment: var a='\User\Downloads\blabla.csv' 
a.replace(/\//g, '\\')
with the above code in JSR223 sampler of jmeter (javascript) it is giving me output as:
UserDownloadslabla.csv

Still not able to get the desired result as '/User/Downloads/blabla.csv'.
I tried all of the answers but could not reached to any conclusion.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: FYI: the java class `FileWriter` on windows automatically converts file path from '/' to '\' and file not found error will look like `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \11\22\33.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)` even you used this code `new FileWriter("/11/22/33.csv", true)`. and this error means file path not found, and nothing about ` \ `  or ` / ` ...

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to replace slashes `/` with backslashes `\`, slashes will work file for Windows platform as well, you can do something like:

   ```
   new File("c:/Windows/system32/cmd.exe")
   ```

   and it will normally resolve.
2. Don't refer variables like `${projectHome}` and/or `${Email}` in scripts, use `vars` shorthand instead. It stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in scope. So you should be using

   ```
   String csvFile = vars.get("projectHome") + "/tenant_details.csv";
   ```

   and

   ```
   String[] params = {vars.get("Email")};
   ```
3. Since [JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity as Beanshell (and will) become a performance bottleneck when it comes to high loads. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In beanshell Sampler/Post-PreProcessor, input the path to script folder and script name into the Script File field as:-

[image]

${__BeanShell(File.separator,)} will return the / in Unix (Mac, Linux, …) and \ in Windows. So you can consider it as:

– Windows: ${PATH}\Foldername\beanshellfile.bsh

– Unix: ${PATH}/scripts/beanshellfile.bsh

Answer (score 0):

Inside Sampler you can call `File.separator` which uses relevant OS  file separator when you need to add it. In your code change to:

```
 String csvFile = "${projectHome}" + File.separator + "tenant_details.csv";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem using BeanShell:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
String JMXPath = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();
char[]a = JMXPath.toCharArray();
log.info(JMXPath + " - It is project JMX path");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] == '\\')
                {
                a[i] = '/';
                }
            }
String xyz = String.valueOf(a);

log.info(xyz + " - It is projectHome value");
vars.put("projectHome", xyz);
```